# How to get value EditText and pass to another activity when select menu actionbar option?

Tags: android

I'm very noob in android programming. I'll like to know how to get value `EditText` and pass to another activity when select menu `ActionBar` option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**In your current Activity, when select menu actionbar, create a new Intent**

```
Edittext txt;
...
String val= txt.getText().toString();

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Key_Name",val);
startActivity(i);
```

**Then in the Next Activity, retrieve those values**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("Key_Name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current value of an EditText, you have to get the Editable
object of the EditText by calling getText() then call toString().

```
Edittext editText;
...
String sValue = editText.getText().toString();
```